# Should source control file directory match solution/project namespaces?

Tags: version-control, team-foundation-server, directory-structure

My team is trying to decide how to best organize/structure our TFS directory. One proposed solution is to create a directory structure that will dictate the namespaces for our c# projects. For instance, if the tfs directory structure for a specific project was TFS\MyApp\Common, then any C# objects in this directory would be under a namespace called TFS.MyApp.Common

Is coupling the TFS directory structure to our solution namespaces a good idea? Could that be hard to maintain after many changes are made inside of projects and solutions? Does anybody do this where you work today?

Comment: The Java language effectively requires that your directory structure mirrors your namespace/package structure. So, yes there are loads of people doing stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

I would not put TFS in your namespaces - it seems redundant and unnecessary.

Typically you'd use namespaces to organize class libraries by related function.  So if you have an API layer for project A, you'd have A.API.  You might also have A.UI.

Those are fine, and the suggestion you made looks good, just don't include the TFS part.